# Missing right parenthesis at create table

Tags: oracle, ddl, create-table, ora-00907

I'm trying to create a basic table (Diak) using an SQL script, and it keeps giving me ORA-00907 on the first line.

However, I create another table (Targy) with basically the same structure, and that gets created just fine.

```
create table Diak (
  Diak_id rowid constraint pk_diak primary key,
  Nev varchar2(100),
  Szul_datum date szul_70_tol constraint check (Szul_datum>= date'1970-1-1'),
  Cim long,
  Kod varchar2(100) constraint uk_diak_kod unique,
  Kezdes_eve number(4) constraint kezdes_88_tol check (Kezdes_eve>= 1988),
  );

create table Targy (
  Targy_id rowid constraint pk_targy primary key ,
  Nev long,
  Kod varchar2(100) constraint uk_targy_kod unique,
  Eloado varchar2(100) default 'Bármi Áron',
  Napok varchar2(100),
  Hely varchar2(100)
  );
```

It says "Error starting at line : 1 in command […] 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" ".
Since Targy table is fine, I don't know what the problem is with Diak table.

Comment: This is why I place commas on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring the `CHECK` constraint properly; just remove the `xxxxx CONSTRAINT` part and you should be fine:

```
create table Diak (
  Diak_id rowid constraint pk_diak primary key,
  Nev varchar2(100),
  Szul_datum date check (Szul_datum>= date'1970-1-1'),
  Cim long,
  Kod varchar2(100) constraint uk_diak_kod unique,
  Kezdes_eve number(4) check (Kezdes_eve>= 1988)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7939d42edd39461a76074b0739df12c6)**.

Note: there is also a trailing comma at the end of the declaration of the last column, but I assume this is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Kezdes_eve>= 1988),
```

Drop that comma and you should be good to go.

Comment: Removing the comma needed, but it is not enough to make the error disappear: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fa7021f72ac5762b0c1028730360dfd0)*